# How to configure Visual Studio project to install dependencies from Nuget

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, dependency-management

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio that it needs to install some packages (like NetMQ) via Nuget automatically just before the first run of the project?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio should do that by default if you're using Visual Studio 2015 and if your package is in your `packages.config`.

[image]

Highlighted options are available in `Visual studio 2013` and `2012` as well.

Comment: The packages are in [`packages.config`](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs/blob/master/aktos-dcs-cs/packages.config) and my Visual Studio 2015 installation has these "automatically download missing packages" options enabled, but I am still having the same problems. Could you have a chance to check out if `examples/pinger_ponger` solution works as it is run: https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs

Comment: The packages are restored for the aktos-dcs-cs project in the solution, but the relative paths in the `.csproj` file don't point to the correct packages directory. it's because your sample solution file lives at a different level than the astos-dcs-cs solution.